# How can I assign a different background-color to an specific item on a list depending on the condition if it is divisible by 3?

Tags: reactjs, components

How can i change the background color of an item on a list in react depending on it's value. I want it to be red if it is divisible by 3.[image]

Comment: Show your effort by writing code instead of placing image of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this example:

```
import React from "react";

export default function NumberList({numbers}) {

    let color = '';
    const listItems = numbers.map((n) => {
        color = (n % 3 === 0)? 'skyblue' : 'lightgreen';
        return  <li style={{backgroundColor:`${color}`}} key={n}>{n}</li>;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import NumberList from "./LIColor";

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let numbers = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            numbers.push(i);

        return (
            <NumberList numbers={numbers}/>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the Red class only when the value is divisible by 3
you can do this

```js
<li key={n.toString()} className={n % 3 === 0 ? 'Red' : ''}>{n}</li>
```